# How to sort and query jsonb data from postgresql query

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a similarity matrix dataframe. The dataframe has two columns: movie_id and similar_movies. The column similar movies is a jsonb object showing cosine similarity to other movies.
Example row 3 (movie_id = 3) in dict:

```
{'movie_id': '3', 'similar_movies': 
'{"0": 0.014912461842819367, 
"1": 0.012710171518762043, 
"2": 0.0013154224298452897, 
"3": 1.0000000000000004, 
"4": 0.013113069599780204,
```

Or like this in df:

[image: df]

Movie Id is 3, and as you see 3 is 1 to 3 because it is the same, and the rest are cosine similarity values. However, the dataset is very large and has dozens of thousands of movies, so it'd be more efficient if I can fetch only the top 10 movies for example from the database level rather than doing the clean up in python.

How can I query the top 10 similarities from the jsonb object so it returns the top 10 similarities. For example I want the output to be:

```
"similar_movies": {
"3": 1.0000000000000004, 
"255556": .8995446778842004, 
"512":  .86214312412155666}
```

The equivalent of this:

`dict(sorted(dict_sim.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[:10])`

but in a query format

Comment: The JSON you show is syntactically incorrect. What are the data stored in the table column? I don't think that it is a good idea to store the data like this. You should normalize, and each similarity number should be in its own table row.

Comment: I am comparing movies to each other, so this will result in an N rows x N columns matrix. Each movie with it's cosine similarity to the other. To store it in postgresql, I  saved the similarity for each movie separate as jsonb object since postgresql doesn't allow many columns. So each movie has a jsonb similarity to all other movies, so only 2 columns are used: the movie_id and similarity_data. What other option do you suggest then?

Comment: To store each similarity value in it's own row, your columns would be movie_id, similar_movie_id, and similarity_value.

Comment: Ahaa I get you. But the dataset would have a lot more rows: num of rows = N x N, instead of just N. Your solution would make it muuuch easier to access the data and sort the movies but would it be more efficient?

Comment: It will very likely be more efficient.

Comment: OK I will try and test your solution and see how it goes. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159.html), JSON array element order is preserved, object key order is not. In PostgreSQL type `jsonb` sticks to it and reorders and deduplicates your keys, but plain `json` preserves both. [From the doc:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#DATATYPE-JSON)

> Because the `json` type stores an exact copy of the input text, it will preserve semantically-insignificant white space between tokens, **as well as the order of keys** within JSON objects. Also, if a JSON object within the value contains the same key more than once, all the key/value pairs are kept. (The processing functions consider the last value as the operative one.) By contrast, `jsonb` does not preserve white space, does not preserve the order of object keys, and does not keep duplicate object keys. If duplicate keys are specified in the input, only the last value is kept.

This means you can [`json_object_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#id-1.5.8.27.5.2.4.15.1.1.1) to preserve the order: [db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/vXHQF-jC)

```sql
select json_build_object( 'movie_id',movie_id,'similar_movies'
                         ,json_object_agg( similar_movie_id
                                          ,similarity order by score) )
from (select movie_id
            ,j.key AS similar_movie_id
            ,j.value::float AS similarity
            ,row_number()over(partition by movie_id order by j.value::float desc) score
      from movie_similarity_aggregated
          ,jsonb_each(similarity_matrix->'similar_movies')AS j)_
where score<=10
group by movie_id;
```

| json_build_object |
| --- |
| {"movie_id" : 0, "similar_movies" : { "0" : 1, "109" : 0.9972348380720784, "89" : 0.996691205306764, "72" : 0.9565037077794105, "76" : 0.9471737433998897, "63" : 0.9439324951948684, "33" : 0.9377223975701177, "3" : 0.931589426258701, "51" : 0.9284534965702238, "138" : 0.9114139796889358 }} |
| {"movie_id" : 1, "similar_movies" : { "1" : 1, "84" : 0.991493954192866, "146" : 0.9887962053265043, "130" : 0.9864403916921192, "156" : 0.9852181900394243, "60" : 0.9834470612311268, "79" : 0.9831763959419084, "3" : 0.9830930813277112, "118" : 0.961002527460247, "105" : 0.9588897340903639 }} |
| {"movie_id" : 2, "similar_movies" : { "2" : 1, "100" : 0.9985089345613372, "42" : 0.994876955757855, "98" : 0.9921820169262852, "38" : 0.9876889415570687, "155" : 0.9843977929737264, "116" : 0.9765158806696135, "174" : 0.969252554993097, "67" : 0.960966239809325, "29" : 0.9572479586848655 }} |

You will probably need to carefully watch what's processing it down the line and how, after you extract it from the db: since the behaviour isn't in the spec, it's likely to change system-to-system - in Python prior to 3.7, you might need to specify [`object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load). You can properly solidify the order by nesting key-value pairs as objects in an array:

```sql
select jsonb_build_object( 'movie_id',movie_id,'similar_movies'
                          ,jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object( similar_movie_id
                                                        ,similarity) 
                                     order by score))
from (select movie_id
            ,j.key AS similar_movie_id
            ,j.value::float AS similarity
            ,row_number()over(partition by movie_id order by j.value::float desc) score
      from movie_similarity_aggregated
          ,jsonb_each(similarity_matrix->'similar_movies')AS j)_
where score<=10
group by movie_id;
```

| jsonb_build_object |
| --- |
| {"movie_id": 0, "similar_movies": [{"0": 1}, {"109": 0.9972348380720784}, {"89": 0.996691205306764}, {"72": 0.9565037077794105}, {"76": 0.9471737433998897}, {"63": 0.9439324951948684}, {"33": 0.9377223975701177}, {"3": 0.931589426258701}, {"51": 0.9284534965702238}, {"138": 0.9114139796889358}]} |
| {"movie_id": 1, "similar_movies": [{"1": 1}, {"84": 0.991493954192866}, {"146": 0.9887962053265043}, {"130": 0.9864403916921192}, {"156": 0.9852181900394243}, {"60": 0.9834470612311268}, {"79": 0.9831763959419084}, {"3": 0.9830930813277112}, {"118": 0.961002527460247}, {"105": 0.9588897340903639}]} |
| {"movie_id": 2, "similar_movies": [{"2": 1}, {"100": 0.9985089345613372}, {"42": 0.994876955757855}, {"98": 0.9921820169262852}, {"38": 0.9876889415570687}, {"155": 0.9843977929737264}, {"116": 0.9765158806696135}, {"174": 0.969252554993097}, {"67": 0.960966239809325}, {"29": 0.9572479586848655}]} |

If you normalise to [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model), you can get the same output without having to unpack the composite field first:

```sql
select jsonb_build_object( 'movie_id',movie_id,'similar_movies'
                          ,jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object( similar_movie_id
                                                        ,similarity) 
                                     order by score))
from (select *,row_number()over(partition by movie_id order by similarity desc) AS score
      from movie_similarity_eav )_
where score<=10
group by movie_id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/4ao_qjbP) you can see it get the simplest and fastest plan at the end. It's also most flexible, lightest and easiest to index and maintain. Even for me just demonstrating this, it was easier to start with EAV and build the denormalised version based on that.